# Generic Classes: Optional Type

Tags: c#, class, generics, option-type

is there a way in C#, to use a generic class with a optional Type.

For Example

Class:

```
public abstract class A<Type> : Interface where Type : new()
{
    public string Method1(int param)
    { ... }
}
```

Call:

```
A<SomeType>.Method1(9);
A.Method1(9);
```

Comment: Does that method needs to access the generic type parameter? if not add it in the base class.

Comment: No it does not, so theres no constraint or something?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, but I'd *strongly* recommend against naming your type parameter `Type`... and that's not the syntax for specifying a type argument to a generic method, either.

Comment: What do you mean by *"use generic class with optional type"*? Do you mean somethings you want to specify a type and sometimes you don't?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov OP wanted to save some time by not typing the generic type argument. He has shown example of how he likes to call it. but it isn't valid though(method isn't static).

Comment: Yeah sure, I would never call it Type...
Im gonna do

A<object>.Method1(9);

Comment: This isn't making any sense. You're declaring an abstract class yet you access an instance method like a static method?. Please clarify your question.

Comment: That won't work either. Your method isn't static. You need a instance to call it. if you have a instance you don't need to specify the generic parameter when calling it. Your question is pretty unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should get your design thinking straight.

You either have a generic class, having fully qualified type names, or you have a non-generic class. It is either one of them. You don't have half classes.

So you could write this:

```
public class A : Interface
{
    public string Method1(int param)
    { ... }
}

A a = new A();
string output = a.Method1(10);
```

Or if you make `Method1` static:

```
string output = A.Method1(10);
```

And then you could optionally derive that one for a generic variant:

```
public class B<T> : A where T : new()
{
}

B<int> b = new B<int>();
string output = b.Method1(10);
```